# PHP: string data- attribute gets split

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm creating buttons from a result set of MySQL query, and binding data- attributes from those results. All fine with numbers and dates, but when the field is a string, the data- attribute created gets split by the whitespaces.

My PHP code:

```
$options = "";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($of)) {
   $options .= "<p><a class='btn btn-default btn-open-modal' role='button' data-id=".htmlentities($row["art_id"])." data-name=".htmlentities($row["art_name"]).">See details &raquo;</a></p>";
}
```

When I inspect the button, I get something like data-name="nike" shox="" (if the name in the table is "nike shox"), but data-id="1" is just fine.

How can I get prevent that the data-name gets split?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this...

```
$options .= "<p><a class='btn btn-default btn-open-modal' role='button' data-id=".htmlentities($row["art_id"])." data-name=".htmlentities($row["art_name"]).">See details &raquo;</a></p>";
```

To this...

```
$options .= '<p><a class="btn btn-default btn-open-modal" role="button" data-id="' . htmlentities($row["art_id"]) . '" data-name="' . htmlentities($row["art_name"]) . '">See details &raquo;</a></p>';
```

Comment: Thanks! Now it works just fine. 

Mind if I ask whats the diference in sorrounding with simple quotes (' ') than double quotes (" ") ?

Comment: The way your code was written, you enclosed your string variable in double quotes. You then tried to use double quotes in the data- attributes. This caused the quotes to become unbalanced. By enclosing the string in single quotes, the double quotes used in the data- attributes did not interfere with the PHP interpreter.